# Sentry: do I need to use Sentry.capture()?

Tags: java, maven, sentry

I am trying to make Sentry work with a maven/Java project. It seems that I can initialize a connection to the Sentry server, however only errors that I specifically catch with Sentry.capture(e) gets loaded to the server. How can I make it so that EVERY uncaught error will be loaded to the server?

I am using the environment variables, and I'm using intelliJ.
In "Run" -> "Edit Configurations..." -> "Environment Variables"

And I inserted SENTRY_DNS="myDNS" SENTRY_SAMPLE_RATE="0.75" as shown in the docs... Do I lack something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your application.

If you are already using a logging framework (log4j, log4j2, logback or java.util.logging) you could use one of those integrations to automatically capture any `logger.error` calls: https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/modules/

If you aren't using a logging framework, or you want to capture other exceptions, then you need to manually capture them with `Sentry.capture(...)`.

Does your application have a main run loop? If it's a server of some kind there is typically a place you can insert a single `Sentry.capture(...)` in the main `try`/`catch` loop. If it's a one-off CLI application then you can just wrap the entire `main` method body.